# Switch Statement Keeps Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I'm fairly new to switch statements in general but please could anyone let me know why my switch statement here is returning undefined? I feel like i've looked at this code for way too long and need another set of eyes to see where i'm going wrong.

Posted the code below. Any input would be much appreciated :)

```
var sizingIndicator = function(){
var isMobile = document.getElementById('panel');
var addToCartSelector = $('.a');
var addToCartSelectorMob = $('.p');

     var standard_size_0 =  '0 (XS)',
        standard_size_2 =  '2 (S)',
        standard_size_4 =  '4 (S)',
        standard_size_6 =  '6 (M)',
        standard_size_8 =  '8 (M)',
        standard_size_10 = '10 (L)',       
        standard_size_12 = '12 (L)',
        standard_size_14 = '14 (XL)';

    var standard_size_0_withoutSML =  '0',
        standard_size_2_withoutSML =  '2',
        standard_size_4_withoutSML =  '4',
        standard_size_6_withoutSML =  '6',       
        standard_size_8_withoutSML =  '8',
        standard_size_10_withoutSML = '10',
        standard_size_12_withoutSML = '12',
        standard_size_14_withoutSML = '14';

    var standard_size_0_additional_info =  '<span class="header">Measurements:</span><span>Bust:<span class="value">30.9</span></span><span>Waist:<span class="value">23.8</span></span><span>Low Hip:<span class="value">34</span></span></div>',
        standard_size_2_additional_info =  '<span class="header">Measurements:</span><span>Bust:<span class="value">31.8</span></span><span>Waist:<span class="value">24.8</span></span><span>Low Hip:<span class="value">35</span></span></div>',
        standard_size_4_additional_info =  '<span class="header">Measurements:</span><span>Bust:<span class="value">33.8</span></span><span>Waist:<span class="value">26.7</span></span><span>Low Hip:<span class="value">37</span></span></div>',      
        standard_size_6_additional_info =  '<span class="header">Measurements:</span><span>Bust:<span class="value">35.8</span></span><span>Waist:<span class="value">28.7</span></span><span>Low Hip:<span class="value">38.9</span></span></div>',
        standard_size_8_additional_info =  '<span class="header">Measurements:</span><span>Bust:<span class="value">37.7</span></span><span>Waist:<span class="value">30.7</span></span><span>Low Hip:<span class="value">40.9</span></span></div>',
        standard_size_10_additional_info = '<span class="header">Measurements:</span><span>Bust:<span class="value">39.7</span></span><span>Waist:<span class="value">32.6</span></span><span>Low Hip:<span class="value">42.9</span></span></div>',
        standard_size_12_additional_info = '<span class="header">Measurements:</span><span>Bust:<span class="value">41.7</span></span><span>Waist:<span class="value">34.6</span></span><span>Low Hip:<span class="value">44.8</span></span></div>',
        standard_size_14_additional_info = '<span class="header">Measurements:</span><span>Bust:<span class="value">44</span></span><span>Waist:<span class="value">37</span></span><span>Low Hip:<span class="value">47.2</span></span></div>';

    var switchCase = function(thisOption){
        switch(thisOption) {
            case standard_size_0:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_0_additional_info);     
            break;
            case standard_size_2:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_2_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_4:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_4_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_6:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_6_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_8:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_8_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_10:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_10_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_12:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_12_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_14:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_14_additional_info);      
            break;     
            case standard_size_0_withoutSML:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_0_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_2_withoutSML:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_2_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_4_withoutSML:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_4_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_6_withoutSML:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_6_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_8_withoutSML:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_8_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_10_withoutSML:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_10_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_12_withoutSML:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_12_additional_info);      
            break;
            case standard_size_14_withoutSML:
                $('#additional_size_info').html(standard_size_14_additional_info);      
            break;                
            default:
            return;
        }    
    };

    var desktopExperience = function(){
        $(".box").on("click", function(index){
            var thisOption = $(this).text();
            switchCase(thisOption);
        });        
        $(addToCartSelector).before('<div id="additional_size_info"></div>'); 
    }; 
    
    var mobileExperience = function(){
      $(".cart").on('click', function(index){
           var thisOption = $(this).text();
           switchCase(thisOption);
      });    
        $(addToCartSelectorMob).after('<div id="additional_size_info"></div>');     
    };

    if(isMobile){
        //fireGaEvent('Selected Size on Mobile');  
        mobileExperience();        
    } else {
        //fireGaEvent('Selected Size on Desktop');  
        desktopExperience();    
    }

};
sizingIndicator();
```

Comment: well, you don't return anything in the switch, except nothing on default, so, what did you expect it to return?

Comment: perhaps `$(this).text()` doesn't match ANY of the cases ... does it?

Comment: You need to return inside the switch, the switch/case just executes the block that matches the case, or the default if no case is met. If you don't return anything inside the case block, it keeps trying to match all the other cases unless you call `break`.

Comment: Whenever you don't return anything from a JS function by default it returns undefined. Which is what is happening in your case. Switch statement doesn't return anything

Comment: Instead of updating value in your switch, try returning the value for each case and setting it in one line afterwards.

Comment: I'm thinking OP is using the wrong terminology;  *returns undefined* - but at no point does the code inspect the return value of `switchCase()`, so possibly OP means "does nothing" or "sets the html to undefined" (or something similar) - a working snippet would help.   Here's a partial fiddle with it working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/4t1o58pq/

Comment: Please edit your question to include enough HTML and a clear description to *recreate* the problem.   It could be that your text doesn't match, for example `.text()` *includes whitespace* so would not match, compare in this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/jmw7Lypz/ (same as above, but 0(XS) has whitespace and doesn't match).  You might just need to do `.text().trim()`

Comment: This was it! It was the .text().trim() that I needed and it's worked!! thankyou so much! :)